# How to match a string with at least one letter, allowing only certain characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regular expression which matches a string with the following conditions. if the string does not match, it will prevent the user from typing(in a UI textbox).

- must have at least one alphabet
- may start or end with `"',-`
- must not have spaces at the start or end
- may contain numbers
- may have space in the middle of the string

This is what I have so far. but it allows the text to end with a space.

```
^["',-]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9"',\ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9"']$
```

Comment: Is `-` allowed in the middle?

Comment: yes its allowed anywhere

Comment: its not a valid case

Comment: you are right. its bit hard to factor in everything. I am thinking hard as I can.

Comment: space between numbers not allowed "1 2"

Comment: Btw, you can scratch rules 5,6 & 8. It's all covered by the 1st one. Whilst the 3rd one also covered the 7th one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?! |.* $)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9"',\ \-]+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeZemh/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of string.
- `(?! |.* $)` - Negative Lookahead: doesn't start or end with a space.
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - Positive Lookahead: contains at least one letter.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9"',\ \-]+` - Match one or more characters including letters, digits, `"`, `'`, `-`, and a space character.
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: it should not allow space in the middle

Comment: @ArunK That contradicts the rules in the question which says _"must **not** have spaces at the **start or end**"_ and _"**may have** space in the **middle** of the string"_. Which one is correct?

Comment: yes sorry. ignore that. I didnt want space between numbers "1 2" . but your regex is covering it too

Comment: @ArunK It will not accept `1 2` but _will_ accept `a 1 2` or `1 2a`, for example. You need to make up your mind about the rules.

Comment: @ArunK See [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8967612).

Comment: thanks so much. I have a question, is it also possible to check whether the maximum string length doesn't exceed 6 characters. I can do this at the application level. Just wanted to see if its possible with regex.

Comment: Sure, you can either add another Lookahead at the beginning (`(?=.{1,6}$)`) or add another alternation to the existing negative Lookahead (i.e., `(?! |.* $|.{7})`). Good luck :)